# Module not Found Error but already installed with pip3

Tags: python, import, speech-recognition, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to import speechrecognition in Pycharm, but I keep getting the same error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kevin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 1, in 
import speechrecognition
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speechrecognition'

The module is installed with pip 3,the message from the terminal:

PS C:\Users\Kevin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5> pip3 install speechrecognition
Requirement already satisfied: speechrecognition in c:\users\kevin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (3.8.1).

I'm using python 3.10.5, the path to speechrecognition is already in the environment variables. I tried reinstalling pycharm and python but the problem persists.
How can I fix it?

Comment: I have found a solution. When creating a new file under the new virtual environment, the "Inherit global site-packages" needs to be checked. I hope it helps others!

Comment: You might be installing it on the system python installation found in C:\Python<Version> and PyCharm is using an installation of python in your account (so at c:\users\kevin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages) 
Verify that pip -V matches python -m pip -V in that folder.